# Trying to convert JS function into C# function

Tags: javascript, c#

I try to convert my function, which uses an RomanNumeral Input to output it as Decimal Value, from JS into C#, but somehow im stuck and really need advice on how to make this Work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class solution
{

static int romanToDecimal(string romanNums)
{
    int result = 0; 
    int [] deci = {1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1};
    string [] roman = {"M", "CM", "D", "CD", "C", "XD", "L", "XL", "X", "IX", "V", "IV", "I"};

    for (var i = 0; i < deci.Length; i++)
    {   
        while (romanNums.IndexOf(roman[i]) == 0) 
        {
            result += deci[i]; 

            romanNums = romanNums.Replace(roman[i], " "); 
        }                                               
    }                                                   
    return result;                                  
}

static void Main()
{

Console.WriteLine(romanToDecimal("V")); //Gibt 5 aus.
Console.WriteLine(romanToDecimal("XIX")); // Gibt 19 aus.
Console.WriteLine(romanToDecimal("MDXXVI"));// Gibt 1526 aus.
Console.WriteLine(romanToDecimal("MCCCXXXVII"));// Gibt 1337 aus.
}

}
```

Comment: Please explain *why* the current code doesn't work

Comment: I don't think XD is 90.

Comment: It should be XC instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace works differently in C#, use substring to remove the first few characters matching:

```
    static int romanToDecimal(string romanNums)
    {
        int result = 0;
        int[] deci = { 1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1 };
        string[] roman = { "M", "CM", "D", "CD", "C", "XD", "L", "XL", "X", "IX", "V", "IV", "I" };

        for (var i = 0; i < deci.Length; i++)
        {
            while (romanNums.IndexOf(roman[i]) == 0)
            {
                result += deci[i];

                romanNums = romanNums.Substring(roman[i].Length);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```